# Unwanted new-line when plugging a string variable into a RichTextBox

Tags: string, vb.net

Im generating a string variable from other string variables that themselves are generated in a button press and take their values from textboxes / user input. Simultaneously, the mass string variable is being loaded into a RichTextBox. While I do purposely use one VbLf in my mass string variable, I am encountering an additional point where a new line begins in my string where it is not supposed too. How can I avoid this?

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        numb = numbtxt.Text
        year = yeartxt.Text
        author = authortxt.Text
        pages = pagestxt.Text
        pgnum = pgnumtxt.Text
        item1 = item1txt.Text
        item2 = item2txt.Text

        format = numb + ") """ + item1 + """" + vbLf + item2 + _
        " - " + author + " (" + year + ") " + pages + " " + pgnum

        rtf.Text = format


    End Sub
```

I am expecting this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXbuQ.png

but I am getting this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0ZOi.png

Any help would be very much so appreciated.

Comment: What does happen, if you remove the underscore (`_`)?

Comment: Remove Carriage Return/Line feeds from the http address (if any): `item2 = item2txt.Text.TrimEnd({ChrW(10), ChrW(13)})`. Possibly, format the string using `String.Format()` or an interpolated string, if available. Something like: `rtf.Text = String.Format("{0}) {1}{2}{3}{4}{5} - {6} (Year {7}) {8} {9}", numb, ChrW(34), item1, ChrW(34), vbLf, item2, author, year, pages, pgnum)`

Comment: @Jimi the trimend solution worked, it was an issue isolated to the textbox. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your content of cour variable `item2` containing the url. I guess, that this variable contains a line break at the end. Try to just print this variable with a leading and trailing char.

If so, you can either replace the new line character in `item2` or try to substring the content.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any unwanted characters from the input strings, you can trim them, or do a character replacement.  For example, to remove CR/LF from the end of strings (untested, from memory);

```
numb = numbtxt.Text.TrimEnd( {vbCr, vbLf, vbCrLf, Environment.Newline} )
```

or to remove all occurrences;

```
year = yeartxt.Text.Replace(vbCrLf, String.Empty)
```

or;

```
year = yeartxt.Text.Replace(vbCr, String.Empty).Replace(vbLf, String.Empty)
```

etc.  YMMV depending on the actual CR/LF character arrangments and language settings!